# Dos Command prompt or Batch file to go to local user directory in windows 7 or 8 or 10

Tags: command, dos, prompt

I tried

cd %user%

but it doesn't take me to the local user directory.  So in the DOS command prompt how to do get there this way.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
cd %USERPROFILE%
```

Or type:

```
set
```

to see all the options for enviornment vars